# Query table with multiple possible values but only get 1 value back

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that holds multiple values in it based on ID and there are flags in the table to identify what the value means.  There is no guarantee that there are records for each flag either.  This is an address field so there are flags in there for Home, Business and Other.  I need to query the table and get home address first if it exists and if it does not exist, grab business.  Not sure how to do that.  This is SQL Server 2016 that I am working with too.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sorry, you are right that I should have given some sort of an example.

Here is what I am looking at:

Table:  Address

ID      Flag     Full Address
123    Home  123 Any Street, Anytown, ST 12345
123    Biz        455 Some Other Street, NewTown, ST 12345
455    Home   4558 Another Street, SomeTown, ST 12345


Results need to be
ID      Flag     Full Address
123    Home  123 Any Street, Anytown, ST 12345
455    Home   4558 Another Street, SomeTown, ST 12345

Answer (score 0):

Use analytical function as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*,
       Row_number() 
        over (partition by id 
              order by case when flag = 'home' then 1 
                            when flag = 'business' then 2
                            else 3 end) as rn
  From t) t
Where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CASE WHEN statement in your query. Something like:

SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN Home IS NOT NULL THEN Home 
WHEN Home IS NULL AND Business IS NOT NULL THEN Business
ELSE NULL
END AS Fixed_Address

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` to partition your data by your customer/person/entity identifier, but prioritize based on your flags to show Home, then Business, and then Other.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId
    ORDER BY IsHome DESC, IsBusiness DESC, IsOther DESC) AS RowNum FROM @Address) T
WHERE T.RowNum = 1
```

This works for following sample data:

```
DECLARE @Address TABLE (
    ID INT, -- ID of the address
    CustomerId INT, -- Whichever field identifies the owner of multiple addresses
    IsHome BIT, -- Flag for home
    IsBusiness BIT, -- Flag for business
    IsOther BIT -- Flag for other
)
INSERT @Address VALUES (1,1,1,0,0), (1,1,0,1,0), (1,1,0,0,1)
```